# How do you install Bluemix Business Rules Designer on MacOS?

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

Installing Bluemix Business Rules Designer on MacOS fails. The older Eclipse 4.2.2 that is required by Rule Designer does not run on MacOS Sierra 10.12. And Business Rule Designer will not install in Eclipse Neon. What steps do I need to take to install Business Rules Designer on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to follow:

1. Download Eclipse 4.2.2 for MacOS and decompress the file.
2. Open a terminal in that folder and run the following command:
   `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Eclipse.app/`
3. Launch that eclipse UNIX executable.
4. Follow the instructions for the Bluemix Business Rules service to install the Rule Designer.

Rule Designer currently requires this older version of Eclipse. The `xattr` command modifies extended attributes that allow you to run this Eclipse version on Mac OS.